# Error: This property is defined but not available in this context

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have created a file with the fields of the Sqlite database but I cannot access the properties from the tableView

DataTableWord.swift

```
    class DataTableWord{
    
    var idWord: Int = 0
    var word: String = ""
    var features: String = ""
    var number: Int = 0
    
    init(idWord: Int, word: String, features: String, number: Int) {
        self.idWord = idWord
        self.word = word
        self.features = features
        self.number = number
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var dataTableWord: [DataTableWord] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataTableWord.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "idCell1Main1", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

cell.cellLabelNumber.text = dataTableWord.[indexPath.row].idWord

return cell
    }


}
```

Why this error message?

[image]

Comment: The error refers to the wrong dot before the `[`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of `idWord` is `Int` but `cell.cellLabelNumber.text` is a string . You can not equalize that two different kind.

Change

```
cell.cellLabelNumber.text = dataTableWord[indexPath.row].idWord
```

With:

```
cell.cellLabelNumber.text = "\(dataTableWord[indexPath.row].idWord)"
```